# Cancel BeginInvoke in WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

In WPF, I am calling
This.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, mydelegete);

Is there a way to cancel later that BeginInvoke method?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` returns a `DispatcherOperation` object. If you retain a reference to it, you can use its `Abort` method to dequeue the operation if it hasn't started executing yet.